# ZF2 url view helper without defined route

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2

So I have a module, named User and inside this module I have some controllers, now I have a logout controller, and I want to create the url(domain.tld/user/logout) for this controller in my views. I tried like this:

```
$this->url("user",array("controller" => "logout")); //This doesn't work
```

I also tried like this:

```
$this->url("user/logout"); //This doesn't work since there isn't a child route defined for the user
```

So my question is, is there an option to define url using the url view helper without defining the routes in the `module.config.php`

Here is a snippet of my `module.config.php`

```
return array(
    'router' => array(
        'routes' => array(
            'register' => array(
                'type' => 'Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Literal',
                'options' => array(
                    'route' => '/user',
                    'defaults' => array(
                        'controller' => 'User\Controller\Index',
                        'action' => 'index',
                    ),
                ),
            ),
            'user' => array(
                'type' => 'Literal',
                'options' => array(
                    'route' => '/user',
                    'defaults' => array(
                        '__NAMESPACE__' => 'User\Controller',
                        'controller' => 'Index',
                        'action' => 'index',
                    ),
                ),
                'may_terminate' => true,
                'child_routes' => array(
                    'default' => array(
                        'type' => 'Segment',
                        'options' => array(
                            'route' => '/[:controller[/:action]]',
                            'constraints' => array(
                                'controller' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                                'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                            ),
                            'defaults' => array(
                            ),
                        ),
                    ),
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to understand what the routing does. The `child_route` you want to access is called `default`. Due to this, the basic route has to be

```
$this->url('user/default');
```

However, as there are no `defaults` assigned, you furthermore need to declare the required parameters for `controller` and `action`. Meaning your route has to look something like that:

```
$this->url('user/default', array('controller' => 'Foo', 'action' => 'Bar'));
```

The way you defined the `user/default` route isn't really that good, too. The first example of `$this->url('user/default')` would actually create the url `domain.com/user/`, which for the router is a valid URL but your `controller` would be highly likely to fail due to missing parameters. Essentially i'd suggest you don't make the controller part optional but only the action and defining a default action.

```
'route' => '/:controller[/:action]'
'defaults' => array(
    'action' => 'index'
)
```

Like this, all requests coming in would be guaranteed to always match up a specific controller and it's `indexAction()`. Naturally you should consider only using this action then for all your controllers under this route.

Comment: Woaw, great knowledge, really appreciate it, thank you it works!